# Cannot find protocol declaration for CCTargetTouchDelegate/CCStandardTouchDelegate

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have upgraded my project to the latest beta of cocos2d 2.1 and I am now receiving the errors,

> Cannot find protocol declaration for CCTargetTouchDelegate

and

> Cannot find protocol declaration for CCStandardTouchDelegate

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As of cocos2d 2.1 beta 3 the following changes have been made to the touch delegates.

> CCTargetedTouchDelegate -> CCTouchOneByOneDelegate
>
> CCStandardTouchDelegate -> CCTouchAllAtOnceDelegate

Simply change the name of the protocol in your class declaration and the error will be fixed.

**Reference**: [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/blob/develop-v2/CHANGELOG)

Comment: OMG those new names are terrible. :(

Comment: it makes my wig burns... and I don't even use a wig.

Comment: It certainly doesn't help that their main touch documentation nearly a year later still doesn't reference these new names and the comments in the source code still reference the old name!

Comment: Seems just `CCTargetedTouchDelegate to CCTouch` was enough for me. I can't be sure just yet though.